# Fastest way to read comma separated files (including datetimes) in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have data stored in comma delimited txt files. One of the columns represents a datetime.

I need to load each column into separate numpy arrays (and decode the date into a python datetime object).

What is the fastest way to do this (in terms of run time)?

NB. the files are several hundred MB of data and currently take several minutes to load in.

e.g. mydata.txt

```
15,3,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,12.2
15,4.5,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,13.7
15,6,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,18.4
15,7.5,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,17.9
15,9,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,17.7
15,10.5,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,16.3
15,12,0,2003-01-01 00:00:00,17.2
```

Here is my current code (it works, but is slow):

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
import numpy

a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
timestmp=[]

myfile = open('mydata.txt',"r")

# Read in the data
csv_reader = csv.reader(myfile)
for row in csv_reader:
  a.append(row[0])
  b.append(row[1])
  c.append(row[2])
  timestmp.append(row[3])
  d.append(row[4])

a = numpy.array(a)
b = numpy.array(b)
c = numpy.array(c)
d = numpy.array(d)

# Convert Time string list into list of Python datetime objects
times = []
time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
for i in xrange(len(timestmp)):
  times.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(timestmp[i], time_format))))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Any help is very much appreciated -thanks!

**(edit: In the end the bottleneck turned out to be with the datetime conversion, and not reading the file as I originally assumed.)**

Comment: Out of interest have you tried running it through pypy?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see what is taking the most time?

Comment: @Tyler Eaves How can this be done? What tools do you use?

Comment: @David, cProfile is handy. If it's installed, all you have to do is type `python -m cProfile myscript.py`.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-cProfile

Comment: Off-topic, but when you find yourself writing lines like `times.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(timestmp[i], time_format))))`, it's a good sign that *something* should be changed.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: No, I wasn't aware of PyPy, but it looks very interesting so I'll try and give it a go soon...

Comment: @Tyler: Numpy isn't properly supported under PyPy, so the point is moot.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: LOL, yes good point! However, when I originally wrote this I was using python 2.4 which (as far as I know) didn't support datetime.datetime.strptime, so I don't know a better way of doing this...

Comment: Just for starters, `tm = time.strptime(timestmp­[i], time_format)` `unix_time = time.mktime(tm)` `dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time)` `times.append(dt)`...

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: is there an advantage to writing it on separate lines?

Comment: It's much more readable than crushing everything into one huge expression.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: OK -fair enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should run your sample script with Python's built-in [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual) to see where the problem actually might be. You can do this from the command-line:

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

Secondly, what jumps at me at least, why is that loop at the bottom necessary? Is there a technical reason that it can't be done while reading `mydata.txt` in the loop you have above the instantiation of the numpy arrays?

Thirdly, you should create the datetime objects directly, as it also supports strptime. You don't need to create a time stamp, make the time, and just make a datetime from a timestamp.
Your loop at the bottom can just be re-written like this:

```
times = []
timestamps = []
TIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
for t in timestmp:
    parsed_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, TIME_FORMAT)
    times.append(parsed_time)
    timestamps.append(time.mktime(parsed_time.timetuple()))
```

I too the liberty of PEP-8ing your code a bit, such as changing your constant to all caps. Also, you can iterate over a list just by using the `in` operator.

Comment: Thanks -this is good advice. After profiling, I've realized that the bottleneck isn't reading from the file (as I had incorrectly assumed) but in fact the datetime type conversion.

Comment: You're right that the separate loop at the bottom for the datetime conversion is not necessary. I've now included it directly within the main loop at the top, however it didn't seem to have much impact in terms of timings.

Comment: Re: use of time.mktime and time.strptime instead of datetime.datetime.strptime directly -I think the reason was that originally I had to run this on python2.4 which didn't support datetime.datetime.strptime. But you're right, on 2.5 or later your method is much neater.

Comment: what version of python are you using now?

Comment: I'm using 2.6.2 now so your method works for me (I'm optimizing some old code). NB. I'm just seeing if I can optimize the code any further using numpy.loadtxt now before I mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. The bottleneck turned out to be the datetime conversion. In the end, I managed to get a dramatic speedup since most of the datetimes were repeated (e.g. several thousand with equal value), so I only did a type conversion on the numpy.unique(times) vastly reducing the number of conversion required. The key was really in profiling my code properly (which I should have done in the first place....I live and learn.)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you can figure it out. You should update your question for others to learn from your findings :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `numpy.loadtxt()`, the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) string has a good example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use `copy=False` when call numpy.array since the default behavior is copy it, this can speed up the script (especially since you said it process a lot of data).

```
npa = numpy.array(ar, copy=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Mahmoud Abdelkader's advice and use the profiler, and find out that the bottleneck is in the `csv` loader, you could always try replacing your csv_reader with this:

```
for line in open("ProgToDo.txt"):
  row = line.split(',')
  a.append(int(row[0]))
  b.append(int(row[1]))
  c.append(int(row[2]))
  timestmp.append(row[3])
  d.append(float(row[4]))
```

But more probable I think is that you have a lot of data conversions. Especially the last loop for time conversion will take a long time if you have millions of conversions! If you succeed in doing it all in one step (read+convert), plus taking Terseus advice on not copying the arrays to numpy dittos, you will reduce execution times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if this will help but you may be able to speed up the reading of the file by using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).  For example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

myfile = open('mydata.txt',"r")
mylist = []
for line in myfile:
    line = line.strip()
    e = line.rindex(",")
    row = literal_eval('[%s"%s"%s]' % (line[:e-19], line[e-19:e], line[e:]))
    mylist.append(row)

a, b, c, timestamp, d = zip(*mylist)
# a, b, c, timestamp, and d are what they were after your csv_reader loop
```